# Number formatting in PythonTeX with `sage` family

Tags: formatting, programming, pythontex, sagetex, number

I am trying to get a special number formatting in `pythontex` with `sage` family but it doesn't work.

Here is an example which shows how it should look like and what I tried so far.

How can I make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto,usefamily=sage]{pythontex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}  

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\sageN}{O{} m}
{%
\sage[#1]{str(#2).replace('.',',')}%
}


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\sageR}{O{} m O{2}}
{%
\sage[#1]{str(round(#2,#3)).replace('.',',')}%
}

\begin{pythontexcustomcode}{sage}
def roundIf(a,n):     
    if (type(a) == type(1.2)) | (type(a) == type(sqrt(2).n())):
        return round(a,n)
    else:
        return a
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\sageRIF}{O{} m O{2}}
{%
\sage[#1]{str(roundIf(#2,#3)).replace('.',',')}%
}

\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{example}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{sagecode}[MySession]
a = 3.42000 ## number with trailing zeros
b = sqrt(3) ## symbolic square root
c = 3/7 ## fraction
d = 5 ## integer
e = pi.n() ## First Decimals of pi
\end{sagecode}

\section*{How it should look like}


\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= 3,42\\ 
b &= \sqrt{3}\\ 
c &= \frac{3}{7}\\ 
d &= 5\\
e &= 3,14159
\end{align*}
\end{example}




\section*{Output with sage}

\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= \sage[MySession]{a}\\ 
b &= \sage[MySession]{b}\\ 
c &= \sage[MySession]{c}\\ 
d &= \sage[MySession]{d}\\
e &= \sage[MySession]{e}\\
\end{align*}
\end{example}


\section*{Output with sageN}


\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= \sageN[MySession]{a}\\ 
b &= \sageN[MySession]{b}\\ 
c &= \sageN[MySession]{c}\\ 
d &= \sageN[MySession]{d}\\
e &= \sageN[MySession]{e}\\
\end{align*}
\end{example}

\section*{Output with sageR}


\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= \sageR[MySession]{a}\\ 
b &= \sageR[MySession]{b}\\ 
c &= \sageR[MySession]{c}\\ 
d &= \sageR[MySession]{d}\\
e &= \sageR[MySession]{e}[5]\\
\end{align*}
\end{example}




\section*{Output with sageRIF}

\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= \sageRIF[MySession]{a}\\ 
b &= \sageRIF[MySession]{b}\\ 
c &= \sageRIF[MySession]{c}\\ 
d &= \sageRIF[MySession]{d}\\
e &= \sageRIF[MySession]{e}[5]\\
\end{align*}
\end{example}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does sage have some "floor" function, that would remove the decimals? Python does, I expect sage would have that too ...

Comment: Yes you can just use pythons floor function. But I think that doesn't help since I don't want to round down. For example my sageRIF function does seem to do the right thing mathematically but the latex output doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the file `pythontex_engines.py` for the sage family the `latex` function of sage is used to preformat the output (`pytex.formatter`):

```
SubCodeEngine('python', 'sage', language='sage', extension='.sage',
              template=python_template.replace('{future}', ''),
              extend = 'pytex.formatter = latex',
              commands='{sage} {file}.sage')
```

So your intended output is additionally modified by the `latex` function. I think that's the point you overlooked.

A possible modification of your code (I took only the last example) could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto,usefamily=sage]{pythontex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}  


\begin{pythontexcustomcode}{sage}
def roundIf(a,n):     
    if (type(a) == type(1.2)) | (type(a) == type(sqrt(2).n())):
        return LatexExpr(str(round(a,n)).replace('.',','))
    else:
        return a
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\sageRIF}{O{} m O{2}}
{%
\sage[#1]{roundIf(#2,#3)}%
}

\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{example}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{sagecode}[MySession]
a = 3.42000 ## number with trailing zeros
b = sqrt(3) ## symbolic square root
c = 3/7 ## fraction
d = 5 ## integer
e = pi.n() ## First Decimals of pi
\end{sagecode}

\section*{How it should look like}


\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= 3,42\\ 
b &= \sqrt{3}\\ 
c &= \frac{3}{7}\\ 
d &= 5\\
e &= 3,14159
\end{align*}
\end{example}


\section*{Output with sageRIF}

\begin{example}
\begin{align*}
a &= \sageRIF[MySession]{a}\\ 
b &= \sageRIF[MySession]{b}\\ 
c &= \sageRIF[MySession]{c}\\ 
d &= \sageRIF[MySession]{d}\\
e &= \sageRIF[MySession]{e}[5]\\
\end{align*}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Another solution might be just to change the formatter in `pythontex_engines.py`, but I dont' see how to modifiy this directly in your tex-file.

Answer (score 1):

First a small modification for the general use where sqrt might not be available
`(type(a) == type(2**(1/2))` instead of `(type(a) == type(sqrt(2).n())`.

Second an extension for the use with complex numbers

```
def roundIf(a,n=16,eps=0):
    if (type(a) == type(1.2)) | (type(a) == type(2**(1/2))):
        return str(round(a,n)).replace('.','{,}')
    elif (type(a) == type(1.2j)) | (type(a) == type((-1)**(1/2))):
        rp=a.real; ip=a.imag
        if (eps>0) & (abs(rp)<eps):
            rp = ''
        elif (eps<0) & (abs(rp)>eps):
            rp = '0.0'
        else:
            rp = str(round(rp,n)).replace('.','{,}')
        if (eps>0) & (abs(ip)<eps):
            ip = ''
        elif (eps<0) & (abs(ip)>eps):
            ip = '0.0\\imath'
        else:
            ip = str(round(ip,n)).replace('.','{,}')+'\\imath'
        if (rp == '') | (ip == ''):
            return rp+ip
        else:
            return rp+'+'+ip
    else:
        return a
```

In case there is a real or imaginary artefact one can decide whether to omit that (eps>0) or print it as zero (eps<0).